# What is the correct Plutus repo tag for Plutus Pioneer Program week01?

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program, git

I'm starting out with the Plutus Pioneer Program at https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-pioneer-program. One of the first steps is to clone the Plutus repo https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus.git from the tag specified in the cabal.project

`tag: 3746610e53654a1167aeb4c6294c6096d16b0502.`

This doesn't appear to be a tag on the Plutus repo. Is it still possible to get the correct Plutus version for the Pioneer Program code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `tag: 3746610e53654a1167aeb4c6294c6096d16b0502` in [cabal.project](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-pioneer-program/blob/main/code/week01/cabal.project) they refer to a commit, not a git tag.

You can find it here: https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus/commit/3746610e53654a1167aeb4c6294c6096d16b0502

So to get the correct version of the repo, you can check out the git commit:

`git checkout 3746610e53654a1167aeb4c6294c6096d16b0502`

Comment: I don't think I have configured anything special in git, but I can `git checkout` with a shortened hash:  `git checkout 3746610e`  - less frightening :-)